# MapProxy - Is it possible to get uniform WMS GetfeatureInfo info_format?

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo, mapproxy, web-gis, standards

This is my very first [`mapproxy`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mapproxy) tagged question, so I hope it makes sense.

I am developing a WebGIS client in my spare time, and now I am mainly focusing on my first type of OGC service: WMS.

Everything worked quite fine so far except one big issue: I could not request a uniform format for any GetFeatureinfo. This is due to the specification (version 1.3.0) not having a default MIME type for the `info_format`. Everytime I receive is either a WMS exception or HTML data that display very differently from service to service.

I have to fix this problem and a quick search led me to [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org) for the first time and I am very excited about it. Especially, [this part of the documentation](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.11.0/configuration_examples.html#featureinformation) where it reads:

> MapProxy supports XSL transformations for more control over feature information. (...) You can use XSLT for sources to convert all incoming documents to a single, uniform format and then use outgoing XSLT scripts to transform this format to either HTML or XML/GML output.

Please can anybody confirm this is one (the?) way to go for my problem, before I start to invest more effort during my spare time to learn how it works?

I must admit I still have to figure out what MapProxy is, but I guess I could even use it to speed up my WMS requests which are super slow (I am currently using [CORS-ANYWHERE](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) in my development env), but this is another argument...

Comment: I'm not sure you'll ever get a consistent GFI response, because service providers can elect to show different information even from the same service dependent on the media type, from not much information in a `text/plain` response, through attribute only information in `application/vnd.ogc.gml` to rich response including JavaScript graphing or summary stats in an `text/html`, and of course they can define other media types.  You're probably asking for trouble if you want to parse and reformat in some consistent fashion for all WMS.